# Catch errors in jsp using jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have this code that register the value num of the text and the checks if it's even or odd, and it works for that, the problem appears when i write a non-numeric value and then i have a 500 error on what i guess it's a *NumberFormatException*

```
<form action="Main" method="post">
    <label>Num: </label><input type="text" name="num" size=2/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>

<c:if test="${num!=null }">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${num%2==0 }">
            <p>${num } is even</p>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <p>${num } is odd</p>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:if>
```

Is there any way to catch it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose you can use `<c:catch>`.

```
<c:set var="num" value="Some string"/>

<c:catch var ="e">
    <c:if test="${num!=null }">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${num%2==0 }">
                <p>${num } is even</p>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <p>${num } is odd</p>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:if>
</c:catch>

<c:if test = "${e != null}"> ${e} </c:if>
```

You'll get:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Some string"
```